# Convert jagged int[][] array to object[][] array

Tags: c#, arrays, casting

There is any way to convert/cast an `int[][]` array into an `object[][]` array?

```
int[][] = FillArray();
object[][] = iArray;
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?  Performance will be affected considerably.

Comment: did you see my code?

Comment: You barely posted any code, lol

Comment: @MattJohnson I know about the performance but the code accept an object array.  Later I will try to change.

Comment: @eddie_cat I posted what I did yet :-)

Comment: You might want to change over to using `List<>` instead. Easier to work with and convert.

Comment: @gunr2171 can I make work List<> as a jagged array?

Comment: @Shaharyar your title edit is invalid. Jagged arrays != multidimensional arrays.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski Agreed ! you are welcome to edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't want to use LINQ, you can use `Array.ConvertAll`.

```
int[][] iArray = FillArray();

object[][] oArray = Array.ConvertAll(iArray, x => Array.ConvertAll(x, y => (object) y));
```

The other answers with LINQ's `Cast` method are okay also.

But as I pointed out in comments, make sure you realize that you are [boxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) each value of the array.  That can lead to performance problems if the array is of any considerable size.

Comment: Thank you for the code but the int[][] array is populate with random values.

Comment: @doro, those values are an example

Comment: That's was just an example. Call your `FillArray` method if you like.  Edited.

Comment: -1 for not using the same random values he is using!

Comment: Well, the code compiled and seems to work.  I am not sure for the result but this is smt else.  Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can do:

```
object[][] objArray = iArray.Select(r => r.Cast<object>().ToArray())
                            .ToArray();
```

Answer (score 3):

Some LINQ:

```
int[][] iArray = FillArray();
object[][] oArray = iArray.Select(i => i != null ? i.Cast<object>().ToArray() : null)
                   .ToArray();
```

Comment: Why have a ternary operator? `int` can't be null, nor can a row.

Comment: @gunr2171 `int` can't be `null`, but `int[]` can.